# libGDX Box2D Assertion Failed

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am using libGDX, and getting an `Assertion failed!` error from box2D:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe
File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp, Line 158

Expression: false
```

looking at the [file](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp), at line 158: `b2Asert(false);`, which is located in the `::Set` function

```
n = tempCount;
if (n < 3)
{
    // Polygon is degenerate.
    b2Assert(false);
    SetAsBox(1.0f, 1.0f);
    return;
}
```

I have been able to find that this is (most likely) rooting from a method that resizes an object's shape:

```
 private void updateShape(CubeComponent cc) {

    // Kill any existing shapes.
    if (cc.fixture != null && cc.fixture.getBody() != null) {
        cc.body.destroyFixture(cc.fixture);
        cc.fixture = null;
    }

    // don't even think about making a non-existing shape. It's almost as
    // bad as dividing by zero.
    if (cc.scale <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Make a fixture
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

    fdef.density = 0.1f;
    fdef.friction = 0.2f;
    fdef.restitution = 0.5f;

    ///////////////Most likely coming from here////////
    // Create the shape.
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.set(new float[] {
            -cc.scale / 2f, -cc.scale / 2f, -cc.scale / 2f, cc.scale / 2f,
            cc.scale / 2f, -cc.scale / 2f, cc.scale / 2f, cc.scale / 2f
    });
    fdef.shape = shape;
    ///////////////Most likely coming from here////////

    // Create the fixture.
    cc.fixture = cc.body.createFixture(fdef);

    // dispose of the bad shape.
    shape.dispose();
}
```

Which shouldn't be caused by the shape being created with a width or height of 0, as I have already checked for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that a shape with a size very close to 0, such as 0.000001, will be treated as a 0.

The fix would change the following from

```
if (cc.scale <= 0) {
    return;
}
```

to

```
if (cc.scale < 0.001f) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-arrange your vertices in shape definition in counter-clockwise direction.